# EF generates duplicated columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im using EF 6.1.3 and EF generates duplicated columns and not generates some tables when I use the update-database -Script command. There are 2 tables with strange and duplicated columns like this.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OrcamentoInsumo] (
    [OrcamentoId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CRId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CodigoTron] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [InsumoId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [FamiliaId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Quantidade] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ValorUnitario] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
    [ValorTotal] [decimal](18, 5) NOT NULL,
    [IsIAC] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsINOC] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [AditivoContratoId] [uniqueidentifier],
    [DataCadastro] [datetime],
    [Observacao] [varchar](150),
    [UsuarioId] [varchar](150),
    [DataCadastro1] [datetime],
    [Observacao1] [varchar](150),
    [UsuarioId1] [varchar](150),
    [Discriminator] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [Insumo_InsumoId] [uniqueidentifier],
    [Usuario_Id] [varchar](128),
    [Insumo_InsumoId1] [uniqueidentifier],
    [Familia_FamiliaId] [uniqueidentifier],
    [Familia_FamiliaId1] [uniqueidentifier],
    [CR_CRId] [uniqueidentifier],
    [CR_CRId1] [uniqueidentifier],
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.OrcamentoInsumo] PRIMARY KEY ([OrcamentoId])
)
```

Here is the Model:

```
public class OrcamentoInsumo
    {
        public Guid OrcamentoId { get; set; }
        public Guid CRId { get; set; }
        public virtual CR CR { get; set; }
        public String CodigoTron { get; set; }
        public Guid InsumoId { get; set; }
        public virtual Insumo Insumo { get; set; }
        public Guid FamiliaId { get; set; }
        public virtual Familia Familia { get; set; }
        public int Quantidade { get; set; }
        public decimal ValorUnitario { get; set; }
        public decimal ValorTotal { get; set; } 
        public virtual bool IsIAC { get; protected set; }
        public virtual bool IsINOC { get; protected set; }
    }
```

And I have the following lines in my context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<InsumoPedido>().Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapInheritedProperties();
                m.ToTable("InsumoPedido");
            });
public DbSet<OrcamentoInsumo> OrcamentoInsumo { get; set; }
```

Here is the Fluet API Code:

```
public OrcamentoInsumoConfig()
        {
            HasKey(o => o.OrcamentoId);

            HasRequired(o => o.CR)
                .WithMany(o => o.OrcamentoInsumo)
                .HasForeignKey(o => o.CRId);

            HasRequired(o => o.Familia)
                .WithMany(o => o.OrcamentoInsumo)
                .HasForeignKey(o => o.FamiliaId);

            HasRequired(o => o.Insumo)
                .WithMany(o => o.OrcamentoInsumo)
                .HasForeignKey(o => o.InsumoId);

            Property(o => o.Quantidade)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(r => r.IsIAC)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(r => r.IsINOC)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(o => o.CodigoTron)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(o => o.ValorUnitario)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(o => o.ValorTotal)
                .IsRequired();
```

Familia Fluent API code:

```
public FamiliaConfig()
        {
            HasKey(f => f.FamiliaId);

            Property(f => f.CodigoTron)
                .IsRequired();

            HasRequired(f => f.TD)
                .WithMany(f => f.Familias)
                .HasForeignKey(f => f.TDId);

            Property(f => f.Descricao)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(null);
        }
```

Here is my IAC class, it has inheritance with OrcamentoInsumo

```
public class IAC : OrcamentoInsumo
    {
        public override bool IsIAC
        {
            get
            {
                return base.IsIAC;
            }

            protected set
            {
                base.IsIAC = true;
            }
        }
        public Guid AditivoContratoId { get; set; }
        public virtual AditivoContrato AditivoContrato { get; set; }
        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
        public String Observacao { get; set; }
        public String UsuarioId { get; set; }
        public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
```

IAC Mappings:

```
public IACConfig()
        {
            HasKey(i => i.OrcamentoId);

            HasRequired(i => i.CR)
                .WithMany(i => i.IAC)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.CRId);

            HasRequired(i => i.Familia)
                .WithMany(i => i.IAC)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.FamiliaId);

            HasRequired(i => i.Insumo)
                .WithMany(i => i.IAC)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.InsumoId);

            HasRequired(i => i.Usuario)
                .WithMany(i => i.IAC)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.UsuarioId);

            HasRequired(i => i.AditivoContrato)
                .WithMany(i => i.IAC)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.AditivoContratoId);

            Property(i => i.DataCadastro)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(i => i.ValorTotal)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(i => i.Observacao)
                .HasMaxLength(null);
        }
```

INOC class, it also have inheritance with OrcamentoInsumo

```
public class INOC : OrcamentoInsumo
    {
        public override bool IsINOC
        {
            get
            {
                return IsINOC;
            }

            protected set
            {
                IsINOC = true;
            }
        }
        public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
        public String Observacao { get; set; }
        public String UsuarioId { get; set; }
        public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
```

INOC Mappings

```
 public INOCConfig()
        {
            HasKey(i => i.OrcamentoId);

            HasRequired(i => i.CR)
                .WithMany(i => i.INOC)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.CRId);

            HasRequired(i => i.Familia)
                .WithMany(i => i.INOCs)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.FamiliaId);

            HasRequired(i => i.Insumo)
                .WithMany(i => i.INOC)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.InsumoId);

            HasRequired(i => i.Usuario)
                .WithMany(i => i.INOC)
                .HasForeignKey(i => i.UsuarioId);

            Property(i => i.DataCadastro)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(i => i.ValorUnitario)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(i => i.ValorTotal)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(i => i.CodigoTron)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(i => i.Quantidade)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(i => i.Observacao)
                .HasMaxLength(null);
        }
```

Comment: Do you also have the reverse mapping in your related entities? eg Familia

Comment: I think not... I update my question with my familia fluent API code.

Comment: I tried reproducing the issue using your input, but had no success - all columns were generated correctly and without duplicates. Do you have classes that inherit your `OrcamentoInsumo`? Seems like something outside the code you provided does this.

Comment: Yes, there are 2 classes that inherit of OrcamentoInsumo, and now that you tell me this, I just realized that thease 2 classes are not generating the tables on the Script. I have another class that is not generating the table too, and it have inheritance too, and the base class also have strange fields in the table, so I think this is the problema. How can I solve this?

Comment: @user3670112 can you add your current mappings for these 2 entities into your post? If I see them I can tell you your mistake. You should also consider the type of inheritance that you want here. Should it be table per entity or table per hierarchy?

Comment: @user3670112 also please include these classes' definitions into your post

Comment: @raderick Im really thankful for your help, I posted the code, if you need any part of my code, just say it. About your question I want a table per entity, so OrcamentoInsumo, IAC and INOC entities, one table each, and I need all OrcamentoInsumo data in my IAC and INOC tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `ToTable("tablename");` to your configurations should solve your issue. For example, it will look this way for your hierarchy:

```
public class  OrcamentoInsumoConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrcamentoInsumo>
{
    public OrcamentoInsumoConfig()
    { 
        ToTable("OrcamentoInsumo");

        HasKey(o => o.OrcamentoId);

        ...
    }
}

public class  INOCConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<INOC>
{
    public INOCConfig()
    {
        ToTable("INOC");

        HasKey(i => i.OrcamentoId);

        ...
    }
}

public class  IACConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<IAC>
{
    public IACConfig()
    {
        ToTable("IACC");

        HasKey(i => i.OrcamentoId);

        ...
    }
}
```

You can check more information about table per concrete class for Entity Framework here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#2.6

Comment: thank you, it solve the problem, just one consideration, I had to rebuild my solution before execute update-database command. When I executed the command without rebuild, it had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Try use data annotations on your model for create foreign objects
try this:

```
public class OrcamentoInsumo
{
    public Guid OrcamentoId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CR")]
    public Guid CRId { get; set; }
    public virtual CR CR { get; set; }

    public String CodigoTron { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Insumo")]
    public Guid InsumoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Insumo Insumo { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Familia")]
    public Guid FamiliaId { get; set; }
    public virtual Familia Familia { get; set; }

    public int Quantidade { get; set; }

    public decimal ValorUnitario { get; set; }

    public decimal ValorTotal { get; set; } 

    public virtual bool IsIAC { get; protected set; }

    public virtual bool IsINOC { get; protected set; }
}
```

I do not advise add primary and foreign keys directly in fluent api, I advise only to more stringent settings.

This can be summarized with data annotation, it is much easier to perform maintenance as the "business rules" of your table will stay in only one class.

Comment: Paulo I tried your approach but the results still the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the extra columns are because you haven't used the fluent api to set up you foreign key relationships constraints so it is generating extra columns

In your fluent api, do something like this.

```
HasRequired(t => t.Familia)
                .WithMany() // Cant see your Familia class
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.FamiliaId);
```

This needs to be done for all of your foreign key relationships.

Comment: I update my question, look I did just as you post, and all FK that I have in InsumoOrcamento is in the Fluent API class.